# Listener always active

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm developing an app and I need to create have a BroadcastReceiver always active even if the app is killed.

I know about 2 ways to do it.

1st: A foreground service registering the BroadcastReceiver with a notification, auto-start active and battery optimization disabled.

2nd: An accessibility service which registers the receiver and every accessibility event the app will verify if the receiver is active. If it's not, it will register the receiver.

I prefer the second option but it is not ideal I belive.

Are there any other options to solve my problem?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What are you trying to achieve? Also, what happens if the device is off or loses connectivity?

Comment: Please see: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.